# python getopt - what's the second returned list?

Tags: python, getopt

I'm learning getops and I don't understand this construction:

```
opts, argv = getopt.getopt(argv, "s:e:", ["start_date=", "end_date="])
```

I tried just to print opts and argv for debugging. First variable - opts is a list of key-value pairs of arguments used and it's values, which is easy and understandable for me, but I completely do not understand the purpose of "argv" variable. Original documentation says:

> the second is the list of program arguments left after the option list
> was stripped (this is a trailing slice of args).

So, when I run my script like this: `python --argument AAA ggg` argv variable will store list with one element "ggg", but what for? Could you please give me any use case for that?

Answer (score 0):

That is meant for positional arguments. Often they are used for filenames that refer to some kind of input or output.

Say you're writing a text editor, you could say that all positional arguments refer to files to open in your editor.

I would not recommend using `getopt`, by the way. [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) does everything `getopt` does but does it better, and allows you to do things `getopt` just can't do. The Python documentation agrees with me:

> The getopt module is a parser for command line options whose API is designed to be familiar to users of the C getopt() function. Users who are unfamiliar with the C getopt() function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the argparse module instead. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#module-getopt))